# How to check the line segment is normal to ellipse?

Tags: geometry

1. My line segment has one end touching the ellipse
2. The other end of the line segment can be outside or inside the ellipse not on the ellipse
3. The ellipse centre is in the origin
4. Line Eqn, $y = mx + c$
5. Ellipse Equation, $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$
6. How to find whether the line segment and ellipse are perpendicular(Normal to each other at
   the point of intersection)?
   [image]

Comment: Are you following a co-ordinate system? What have you tried?

Comment: The ellipse center is in the origin

Comment: Calculate the tangent line to the ellipse at the point *your* line touches the ellpise: your line and the tangent line **must** be perpendicular ...

Answer (score 2):

If you take the derivative of the ellipse at that point, multiply it by the slope of the line, you will get -1 if the line is perpendicular to the ellipse.

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ take derivative of both sides

$\frac{2x}{a^2}+\frac{2yy'}{b^2} = 0$

$y' = \frac {-xb^2} {ya^2}$

now you want to find where the line and the ellipse intercept.

$y = mx + c$

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{(mx + c)^2}{b^2}=1$

$b^2x^2+a^2(m^2x^2 + 2mx + c^2)=a^2b^2$

$(a^2m^2 + b^2)x^2+2a^2mx + c^2a^2 -a^2b^2 = 0$

from here you solve using the quadratic formula using the real values. You then find $y'$ at that point, and multiply it by m. If it equals -1, your line is perpendicular to the ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [interesting geometric property](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AngleBisectorsInEllipse2.shtml) of ellipses (and similarly for other conic sections).

The application to your special case is this:

Draw two lines from the point $P$ on the ellipse to the foci $F_1$ and $F_2$.

The internal angle bisector of these lines (i.e. angle bisector of $\angle F_1PF_2$) is the normal to the ellipse.

The external angle bisector is the tangent line to the ellipse at $P$.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the dot product, start with deriving your ellipse equation with respect to x, put y prime in one side and all the rest in the other side.
now treat the other side of y prime as a vector in 2d, that vector represent the slope of your ellipse. you need to know the slop of the line you want to check, also write its slope as 2d vector. finally get the dot product of the 2 vectors, if the result is zero then that line is a normal on the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apply ordinary calculus. Using the equation for the ellipse, you can easily compute the tangent slope at every point. For every tangent line that you create at a point, there is a perpendicular to that line through the same point. You should be able to arrive at a formula for the slope of the perpendicular line to the tangent line through any given point of the ellipse this way.

Of course instead of thinking of the line segment, you can think about the line it defines. The line will miss the ellipse completely or else intersect the ellipse. When the line intersects the ellipse you can find the point of intersection and compare the slope of the incident line to the slope your formula says the slope of the normal should be.

Comment: I found the intersection point and the slope of the line but how to   find the slope of the ellipse at that point.

Comment: @andikatdennis I'm hoping you can do some ordinary calculus :) If you express the ellipse as an equation in variables $x,y$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ tells you the slope of the tangent at each point. Can you provide an equation for the ellipse and do the derivative?